# Why the load test values are different in siege - 3.0.8 and siege 4.0.4?

Tags: load-testing, siege

I have run this command `siege -c50 -d10 -t3M http://www.example.com`  in both the versions `3.0.8` and `4.0.4`. I got a totally different result. Can anyone give me a solution for this and why do the values differ in these versions..?

**In version 4.0.4**

```
Transactions:               1033 hits
Availability:             100.00 %
Elapsed time:             179.47 secs
Data transferred:          26.31 MB
Response time:              8.45 secs
Transaction rate:           5.76 trans/sec
Throughput:             0.15 MB/sec
Concurrency:               48.63
Successful transactions:        1033
Failed transactions:               0
Longest transaction:           72.85
Shortest transaction:           3.65
```

**In version 3.0.8**

```
Transactions:           133 hits
Availability:        100.00 %
Elapsed time:        179.08 secs
Data transferred:         27.59 MB
Response time:        50.95 secs
Transaction rate:          0.74 trans/sec
Throughput:        0.15 MB/sec
Concurrency:          37.84
Successful transactions:         133
Failed transactions:              0
Longest transaction:         141.14
Shortest transaction:          8.34
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML parsing was added to version 4.0.0 and it is enabled by default. It makes an additional request for resources like style sheets, images, javascript, etc.

We can enable/disable this feature in the **siege.conf** file, by setting the value of parser to true/false.

[Setting parser value in the siege.conf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLOxp.png)